# jquery replace a number (1 to 5) with a html element to create a star rating

Tags: jquery

I need to replace the digit (1 to 5) multiple times in the following `<span>`:

```
<div>English <span class="star-rating">3</span></div>
<div>French <span class="star-rating">4</span></div>    
<div>German <span class="star-rating">5</span></div>
<div>Italian <span class="star-rating">4</span></div>
<div>Spanish <span class="star-rating">3</span></div>
<div>Portuguese <span class="star-rating">1</span></div>    
<div>Arabic <span class="star-rating">1</span></div>
```

with ready 'star rating' style sheet classes:

For 1 star:

```
<i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i>
```

For 2 stars:

```
<i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i>
```

For 3 stars:

```
<i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i>
```

For 4 stars:

```
<i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i>
```

For 5 stars:

```
<i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i>
```

I have tried this jquery but nothing seem to happen:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".star-rating").html().replace('1','<span class="star-rating"><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i></span>');
    $(".star-rating").html().replace('2','<span class="star-rating"><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i></span>');
    $(".star-rating").html().replace('3','<span class="star-rating"><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i></span>');
    $(".star-rating").html().replace('4','<span class="star-rating"><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i></span>');
    $(".star-rating").html().replace('5','<span class="star-rating"><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o star-full"></i></span>');
})
</script>
```

Any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need jQuery for this simple task, CSS works just fine.

See this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/axbyed9t/

Here is the modified link sample which has classes with # so you can easily dynamically output html markup if you were doing it before as 1,2,3
https://jsfiddle.net/axbyed9t/2/

So instead of just outputting 1, 2, 4 inside the span, just add it to the span's class i.e. s1 s2 s3 or star1 , star2 etc.. then have classes in CSS with appropriate unicode for FontAwesome.

For filled star use: \f005 
For Empty star use : \f006

HTML code example:

```
<div>English <span class="star-rating star3">3</span></div>
<div>Portuguese <span class="star-rating star1">1</span></div>
```

And CSS will be:

```
 .star-rating.star3:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f005\f005\f005\f006\f006";
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.star-rating.star1:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f005\f006\f006\f006\f006";
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this answer. No need jQuery indeed.

Comment: Very nice, sometimes we don't need js or such things.

Answer (score 1):

Just return the element `n` times

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".star-rating").html(function(_,n) {
        return Array.apply(null, Array(+n)).map(function() {
            return $('<i />', { 'class' : 'fa fa-star star-full' });
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you should take a look at `Angularjs`, he provide usefull functions to change the view dinamically, for exemple by using `ng-repeat` you should just have something like:

```
<img ng-repeat="limitTo: yourVariable" src="localhost/path/yourImg.jpg">
```

EXPLANATIONS:

yourVariable: just recover the number of stars you want to show and set this variable to the number you have.

limitTo is just one of the many ng-repeat filters, you can use a variable, a function who returns true/false (but i recommend using custom filters instead) to properly filter your loop in a specific way.

Really, for stuff like that you should use Angular.

Btw, sorry for grammar, french baguette right here.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the outcome of your replace statement to the html. But even then, this will fail.

You can do something like this to make your life easier. It ain't perfect, but it will do the trick

*I hope it will work, it's untested code, but you get the idea*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var full = '<i class="fa fa-star star-full"></i>';
    var empty = '<i class="fa fa-star-o star-empty"></i>';
    $(".star-rating").each(function() {
        var stars = parseInt($(this).text());
        var html = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if(stars > i) {
               html += full;
            } else {
               html += empty;
            }
        }
        $(this).html(html);
    });
});
```